# How to disable submit button after checking if username and email exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using AJAX, I'm checking whether an email or username exists in the database. I want to disable the submit button if one of the two (or both) exist.

Right now i managed to color the input border, but I'm stuck on the logic to disable the button.

I disable the submit button using:

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
```

What logic and where should I apply to disable the button?

```
$(function() {
  $("#username").on("change", function() {
    var user = document.forms["reg_form"]["username"].value;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'api/checkdata.php',
      data: {user: user},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(r) {
        if(r=="1") {
          //Exists
          $("#username").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
          //Doesn't exist
          $("#username").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  $("#email").on("change", function() {
    var email = document.forms["reg_form"]["email"].value;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'api/checkdata.php',
      data: {email: email},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(r) {
        if(r=="1") {
          //Exists
          $("#email").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
          //Doesn't exist
          $("#email").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply when you get the result from server which says username or email exist, you will disable submit button
as well :

```
$(function () {
  $('#username').on('change', function () {
    var user = document.forms['reg_form']['username'].value;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'api/checkdata.php',
      data: {user: user},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (r) {
        if (r == '1') {
          // Exists
          $('#username').css('border-color', '#ff0000');
          $('#submit').addAttr('disabled');
          isValid=false;
        } else{
          // Doesn't exist
          $('#username').css('border-color', '#2cbc21');
          $('#submit').addAttr('disabled');
          isValid=true;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  $('#email').on('change', function () {
    var email = document.forms['reg_form']['email'].value;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'api/checkdata.php',
      data: {email: email},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (r) {
        if (r == '1') {
          // Exists
          $('#email').css('border-color', '#ff0000');
          $('#submit').addAttr('disabled');
          isValid=false;
        } else {
          // Doesn't exist
          $('#email').css('border-color', '#2cbc21');
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
          isValid=true;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});

$("#submit").on('click',function(){
  if (isValid){
    //here you can submit form and both username and email dosenot exists
  }
});
```

not with isValid variable if email not exists but username exist isValid will be false and form won't be submitted

Comment: yes, but then when the username/email is changed it will remain disabled.
if you add a disabled=false in else, it causes other problems, like if the username is not valid thus disabling the button, then when the email is checked and is valid it enables the button, but it is enabled when the username is still not valid

Comment: @Andreas let me edit my answer to re-enable button if email or username is not exists

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm pasting my comment from below:

 
i've tried this and unfortunately doesn't work. In this case, if the username is not valid it will disable the button, as expected. But then, if the username is not changed and email is correct it will enable the button, something not expected as the username is still not valid.

Comment: @Farhad Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do so using `.attr("disabled", true);` then enable it using `$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");` try this :

```
        $(function() {

        $("#username").on("change", function() {

            var user = document.forms["reg_form"]["username"].value;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/checkdata.php',
                data: {user: user},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(r)
                {
                    if(r=="1")
                    {
                        //Exists
                        $("#username").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
                        //disable button using prop
                       $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
                    }else{
                        //Doesn't exist
                        $("#username").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
                        // remove disabled
                        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                }
            });

        });

        $("#email").on("change", function() {

            var email = document.forms["reg_form"]["email"].value;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/checkdata.php',
                data: {email: email},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(r)
                {
                    if(r=="1")
                    {
                        //Exists
                        $("#email").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
                         //disable button using prop
                        $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
                    }else{
                        //Doesn't exist
                        $("#email").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
                        // remove disabled
                        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                }
            });

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question correctly, you want to change to the disabled state at the same time you set the disabled style. Put the line right before or after the calls to .css().

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

$("#username").on("change", function() {

    var user = document.forms["reg_form"]["username"].value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/checkdata.php',
        data: {user: user},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
        if(result != 'false'){
          $('#message').text('Username exists');
          $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
    });

});

$("#email").on("change", function() {

    var email = document.forms["reg_form"]["email"].value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/checkdata.php',
        data: {email: email},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
        if(result != 'false'){
          $('#message').text('email exists');
          $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add button disable enable logic as follows. If the username or email exists you should enable, otherwise disable.

```
$(function() {

$("#username").on("change", function() {

    var user = document.forms["reg_form"]["username"].value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/checkdata.php',
        data: {user: user},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r)
        {
            if(r=="1")
            {
                //Exists
                $("#username").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            }else{
                //Doesn't exist
                $("#username").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    });

});

$("#email").on("change", function() {

    var email = document.forms["reg_form"]["email"].value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/checkdata.php',
        data: {email: email},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r)
        {
            if(r=="1")
            {
                //Exists
                $("#email").css("border-color", "#ff0000");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            }else{
                //Doesn't exist
                $("#email").css("border-color", "#2cbc21");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

});

});

Comment: i've tried this and unfortunately doesn't work. In this case, if the username is not valid it will disable the button, as expected. But then, if the username is not changed and email is correct it will enable the button, something not expected as the username is still not valid.